# Make program continue action till line has been created

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, while-loop

Currently my program takes line1 such as "taaaaaaaaaaNataggggggggggNccc" and will cut 1 character of the end untill it matches line2 such as "taaaaaaaaaaNcccggggggggggNccc" and once they match it concatenates them together to form line3, however if they dont match it should cut another character off. How can I make it repeat the cutting action until they match and line3 has been made? I have thought about for and while loops but am unsure how to state this issue. Everything else about this program works as it should but when it tries matching them if it fails it just stops and wont go back to try trimming again.

I have tried the below code where magic(matching) is essentially the counting code used to idnetfy how much the 2 lines match and if below 8 it should repeat the cutting. However when used it asks for matching and magic to be stated before the while loop which is right at the start and this messes up the rest of the code.

```
while magic(matching) >=8:
    line3=line1+line2
        print ("Matching and merging has occured as shown below")
        print (line3)
```

The code of interest is below:

```
       n = 0
        consec_matches = []
        chars = defaultdict(int)    
for k, group in groupby(zip(line1_u_i, line2_u_rev_comp_join_i), class_chars):
        elems = len(list(group))
        chars[k] += elems
        if k == 'match':
        consec_matches.append((n, n+elems-1))
    n += elems
print ("Print chars below")
print (chars)
print ("Print consec_matches below")
print (consec_matches)
print ([x for x in consec_matches if x[1]-x[0] >= 9])
print (" Matches longer than 10 below")
list = [x for x in consec_matches if x[1]-x[0] >= 9]
flatten_list= [x for y in list for x in y]
print (flatten_list)
print ("Flatterend list")
matching=[y[1] for y in list for x in y if x ==0 ]
print ("Matching list below")
print (matching)
magic = lambda matching: int(''.join(str(i) for i in matching) or 0)
print (" Print magic matching below")
print (magic(matching))
line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l = line2_u_rev_comp_join_i[magic(matching):]
print ("Print line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l type below")
print (type(line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l))
print ("Print line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l sequence below")
print (line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l)
line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l_str = ''.join(line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l)
print ('List of line2 converted to string')
print ("List2 before as list below")
print (line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l)
print ("Line 2 reprinted when string as below")
print (line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l_str)
print (line1_u_i)
print ("Magic below")
print (magic)
if magic(matching) >=8:
    line3=line1_u_i+line2_u_rev_comp_join_i_l_str
    print ("Matching and merging has occured as shown below")
    print (line3)
else:
    continue
```

The cutting code is:

```
line2_u_rev_comp_join_i = line2_u_rev_comp_join[1:]
line1_u_i = line1_u[:-1]
```

Comment: Please rewrite more clearly. Are you attempting to find the largest common substring?

Comment: I have now added the code for the merging I am doing to the strings, as shown it is not LCS I am trying to get but see if the frist 10 characters from both match and if so they can attach together.

Comment: if first ten chars match concat strings?

Comment: Yup thats pretty much it. As I say the code all works by itself but It wont return to the cutting if the merging fails which is what I cannot work out

Comment: @Tom, I answered based on wanting the first ten chars of each to match, if that is not what you want you will have to add more detail to your question.

Comment: Right with the code I already had it checked each key within both lines to see if they matched, it then identified sequences longer than 10 characters that matched and provided their details. Then from this if from 0 to 9 matched then those would be deleted from one line and the 2 merged, creating line3 which is as if both lines had been 1 to begin with and so doesnt have a repeating middle section but as I say this should only occur if it matches from 0 to at least 9 and then I will allow an option later on so if people want to allow a mismatch if from 0 to 9 match and 11 to 30, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = "taaaaaaaaaaNataggggggggggNccc"
l2 = "taaaaaaaaaaNcccggggggggggNccc"
l1_ten=l1[0:10] # first ten chars
l2_ten=l2[0:10] 
if l1_ten==l2_ten:
    print l1_ten+l2_ten
taaaaaaaaataaaaaaaaa
```

If you want the chars that are equal at the same index in each string.

```
l1 = "taaaaaaaaaaNataggggggggggNccc"
l2 = "taaaaaaaaaaNcccggggggggggNccc"
count = 0
slice = 0
new_s=''
while count < len(l1):
    if l1[slice]==l2[slice]: 
        new_s+= l1[slice]
    count += 1
    slice += 1
new_s
In [13]: new_s
Out[13]: 'taaaaaaaaaaNggggggggggNccc'
```

You can just use a for loop to achieve the same:

```
new_s1=""
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] ==l2[i]:
        new_s+=l1[i]
```

I have assumed you are using strings of equal lengths